# Update Each Array-Object Value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically I want to update each table column for a Model in Rails 5.

```
str = "abc---def"

str.split('---').map do |a|
 Foo.where(product_id:1).update_all(bar: a)
end
```

**Old object would be like:**

```
[
 [0] { product_id: 1,
       ...,
       bar: "xxx",
       ...
     },
 [1] { product_id: 1,
       ...,
       bar: "xxx",
       ...
     }

]
```

**New should be like:**

```
[
 [0] { product_id: 1,
       ...,
       bar: "abc",
       ...
     },
 [1] { product_id: 1,
       ...,
       bar: "def",
       ...
     }

]
```

But what I got is `bar: "def"` for each. Is there a clean method in rails to achieve what I want? `update_attributes` gives an error.

Is the title name correct?

Comment: First of all your question is not so explanatory. How do you expect to return multiple records while querying on ID (primary key) ?

Comment: Let me tell you what I understood from your question. 
So you saying you have an array of values (after string spliting) 
And you have multiple Model objects (after querying) and you want each value to be set for model in same order , right ?

Comment: @QaisarNadeem Thanks for that. Post updated.

Comment: okay lemme right an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all let's get started from some basics.

You want to update multiple rows and want to set different value for each row. So it cannot be done in single query like you are doing. So you need to loop through the `Foo` objects and set each one separately.

So let's assume

```
str = "abc---def---ghi---jkl"
tokens = str.split('---') 
foos_to_update = Foo.where(product_id: 1) #Let's assume it will return 4 or lesser records. (otherwise you need to tell what do you wanna do if it returns more then `tokens`)
foos_to_update.each_with_index {|foo,i| foo.update(bar: tokens[i])}
```

The last line is looping through returned objects and setting the `bar` value for each object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using `Foo.where(id:1).update_all` to update a single record may work, but is non-idiomatic. It's better to use `Foo.find_by(id: 1).update`. For getting single records, I prefer to use `find_by` instead of `find` because it returns `nil` instead of raising NotFound errors, but that's a personal preference.

Second, the way you're using `update_all(bar: a)` is giving you unexpected results. In a `map` block, the returned value becomes part of the resulting array. `update_all` doesn't return the record which were changed. It returns an integer showing the count of records which were changed. Similarly, `update` doesn't return the record. It returns `true` or false` depending on if the validations passed.

Tying together these concepts, the following code can be written:

```
str = "abc---def"    
str.split('---').map do |a|
 foo = Foo.find_by(id:1)
 foo&.update(bar: a)
 foo
end

# note that you could instead write `foo.update(bar: a)` if you
# don't want to use the safe navigation operator
```

Or another way to write it which does the same thing:

```
str = "abc---def"
str.split('---').map do |a|
 Foo.find_by(id:1)&.tap { |foo| foo.update(bar: a) }
end
```

Note that in these examples I'm using the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) which is in Ruby versions newer than `2.3`. It helps prevent `NoMethodError` on nil objects, but isn't really necessary.

Comment: What is `&.tap`? Rails 5 method?

Comment: [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) is in Ruby core since 1.9. It's not an essential method to use. I think it's benefit is mostly stylistic, adding readability. The `&.` is the safe navigation operator which I linked to.

Comment: I had to accept Qaisar's answer as it's more clear to me. However. none of you answer worked. I've tried many times. The last code never updated the table column. First got a syntax error here: `foo&.update(file_file_name: a)`

Comment: Because you're not using Ruby 2.3. You can remove the `&` and it will work.