# Update Model with column objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, object, ruby-on-rails-5

I do hope the title is correct. Using a Rails 5 project with PostgreSQL and Ruby 2.3.1.

I have enabled [hstore](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#hstore) in my app. I do not know the correct way to update a table column with an object data. Make sense?

```
# There will be only two arrays:
cars = ["honda", "bmw"]
rate = [1, 2]

cars.zip(rate).map do |c,r|
  Foo.find(1).update_attributes(bar: {c => r})
end
# Foo.find(1).bar = {"bmw" => 2}
```

**I expect:**

```
# Foo.find(1).bar = {"honda" => "1", "bmw" => 2}
```

How to get the two values into `bar`?

I was trying to fit [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106321/update-each-array-object-value-in-rails) into this but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hash from the array

```
 a = cars.zip(rate)
 Foo.find(1).update_attributes(bar: Hash[a])
```

or if you need some enumerator

```
 cars.zip(rate).each_slice(2) { |x| Foo.find(1).update_attributes(bar: Hash[x]) }
```